# Call-by-reference and Call-by-value

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference, call-by-value

I am writing a program that lets the user input an integer into the variable `value`, and calls the two alternate functions, each of which triples the chosen integer value. 
The function `triple_by_value` passes the variable number by value, triples the parameter and returns the result.

The function `triple_by_reference` passes the variable number by reference, and triples the original value of number through the reference parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a number (-1 to end): ";
    cin >> value;

    if (value != -1)
    {
        triple_by_value(value);
        cout << "Triple-By-Value: " << value << endl;
        triple_by_reference(value);
        cout << "Triple-By-Reference: " << value << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int triple_by_value(int value)
{
    value *= 3;
    return value;
}

int triple_by_reference(int &value)
{
    value *= 3;
    return value;
}
```

It seems I'm having a problem where the function `triple_by_value` isn't, well, tripling the value, just printing it as is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "The function TripleByValue passes the variable number by value, triples the parameter and returns the result." and your code promptly throws that result away.

Comment: It's like you're explaining your code perfectly, and then somehow forget what you yourself just said :p

Comment: @keyser I get that sometimes xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name suggests, passing a variable by value means that the function only gets the value of the variable and not access to the variable itself.

In your example, `int value` is a whole different variable from `value` in `main`, just that it has the same value. However, `int &value` is a reference to `value` in `main`, which means it is safe to think of it as the `value` in `main` itself.

If you print `value` in `triple_by_value` after `value *= 3` you will get the value that you want. If you want `value` in `main` to have the new value, you can assign the new value to `value` in `main` by doing `value = triple_by_value(value);` in `main`, or simply use `triple_by_reference`.

Comment: It seems that I didn't notice that I was creating a new variable within the function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Although my teacher have tripled the value using a call-by-value. How so?

Comment: @LeonardoNammour It's mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I haven't seen it, excuse me :p kudos, mate. You're the best!

Comment: @LeonardoNammour The part with `value = triple_by_value(value);`. :D

Comment: using `cout << "Triple-By-Value: " << triple_by_value(value)` fixed my problem. Using `value = triple_by_value(value)` would just keep the value as is and as a result the call-by-reference function will multiply the initial value by 6.

Comment: Oh so that's what you wanted to do! Glad your problem's solved :D

Comment: that's the same concept though, using the _return value_